# VLookup search for columns concatenation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have a search term which spans into 3 columns.

```
text_A, text_B, text_C
```

I'm trying to find the `A` column value for a row which forms almost the same values:

```
text_A, text_B, text that starts with text_C
```

I get no result even before handling the search of `starts with text_C`, even though I expected to get one.

Any tip on how to change this?

```
=VLOOKUP(I10:I&"^"&J10:J, C10:C&"^"&D10:D, 1, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: might it be easier with a QUERY?

Comment: can you please try to write it?

Comment: I can, but I am not sure I understand. We are supposed to return the value of column A in rows where I and J are the same up until the underscore and so are C and D? For equality it would look like =QUERY(A1:J5,"SELECT A where C=D AND I=J") if I understand the question.

Comment: I think I now understand. If so, it would look like =QUERY(A1:J5,"SELECT A where C=D AND I=J AND F starts with E")

Comment: Did the solution provided above work for your use-case?

Comment: It turns out the query solution does not work because the matches need not be in the same row,

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I10:I&"^"&J10:J, {C10:C&"^"&D10:D, E10:E}, 2, 0)))
```

---

### update

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I10:I&"×"&J10:J&"×"&K10:K, 
 {C10:C&"×"&D10:D&"×"&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E10:E&"", 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(K10:K, 1, 0)))), B10:B}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do `starts with text_c`? How would you return data from `column A` which is out of the range?

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11IXzW2tWdQDU-f2I_gEiIp_1HUZmTAdjeDE9pF_UGPw/edit?usp=sharing